# Field validation in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, request, asp.net-core-2.0

I get a JSON string in a body of a POST Request like this:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "email": "example@test.com",
    "password": "example"
  }
}
```

My question is, how can I validate the **email** and **password** field in **ASP.NET Core 2.0**?

Comment: There are many ways to do validation.  A what have you tried?

Comment: I tried the build in functionallity of ASP with the annotations and the modelstate. But I don't know if I should create one request class for every request or one class for one request.

Comment: the number of request models depends on your entity structure. you can inherit attributes from base classes if you want to have some re usability.

Comment: You need to give us a little more detail.  What kind of validation do you want?  Do you want server side validation or client side validation (or both)?  What have you tried so far?  What has worked, what hasn't?

Comment: That was my fault, I want server-side validation. I use C# in the backend.
My problem is that I am not sure if it is good to create more than one request class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create the model with data annotation validation attributes. There are a number of out of the box validation attributes, and you can also create your own.

```cs
public class SomeRequest
{
    [Required]
    public SomeRequestPayload Payload {get;set;}
}
public class SomeRequestPayload
{
    [RegularExpression("some regex", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email")]
    [Required]
    public string Email {get;set;}
    [RegularExpression("some regex", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Password")]
    [Required]
    public string Password {get;set;}
}
```

Then check the `ModelState` in your controller action. MVC will validate the model and hold any errors in the `ModelState` when it binds the request body to the method parameter.

```cs
[HttpPost("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostPayload([FromBody] SomeRequest someRequest)
{
    //checking if there was even a body sent
    if(someRequest == null)
         return this.BadRequest("empty");
    //checking if the body had any errors
    if(!this.ModelState.IsValid)
         return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
    //do insert here
    return this.Created("someLocation", someModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to validate those fields. I prefer to use `FluentValidation` library with additional package `FluentValidation.AspNetCore`, which integrates validation into `ASP.NET Core pipeline`.

There is a great [blog-post](https://cecilphillip.com/fluent-validation-rules-with-asp-net-core/) about using this approach.

Put simply, you should do a few steps:

`dotnet add package FluentValidation.AspNetCore`

```
public class AuthViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<AuthViewModel>
{
    public AuthViewModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(reg => reg.Email).NotEmpty().EmailAddress();
        RuleFor(reg => reg.Password).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

Add some code to `ConfigureServices`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
            .AddFluentValidation(fvc =>
                fvc.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
}
```

And finally validate a model

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult FormValidation(AuthViewModel model)
{
    if (this.ModelState.IsValid) {
        ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Great!";
    }
    return View();
}
```